# Unity Video Player URL Dropbox Video Streaming has bug when build to android, but works fine in editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, url, video-streaming

I am using the video player component to stream my video that is hosted on Dropbox.  I have no problem when I tested it on the editor. But when I build it to Android, it will only stream for the first 10 seconds then it just suddenly stopped streaming. The video will be rendered on a "RenderTexture" and use as a skybox.

I had tried using other links and had no problem on both editor and android. So I wonder is it Dropbox that cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Video player component is not fully supported by android you should try to use Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie

Comment: I think I had missed some info, I want the video to render on a "RenderTexture", I will edit my question. Thx for the reply